# C program how to Check array first space

Tags: c, arrays

In my program, i don't know how to check array for the first space

for example

```
char *array[] ={'a','d','d','M',' ','-','P',' ','e'};
```

How to get first space and get first space before length in array

Here is my program:

```
 printf("Please enter appointment: \n");
 n = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,80); /* read a line */
 int result=strncmp(buf, "addM", get first space before length);

switch (result)
case 0: go to other function
```

or other method to compare first space before array string

Comment: What do you mean by `get first space before length in array` and `first space before array string`?

Comment: you probably want a null-terminated string

Comment: i think that i need get first space before string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strchr()` to locate a character in a character array:

```
#include <string.h>

char *space_ptr = strchr(array, ' ');
int posn = -1;
if (space_ptr != NULL)
{
   posn = space_ptr - array;
}
```

Comment: Where did this function come from?

Comment: I believe `index` from `strings.h` is considered legacy/deprecated. `strchr` from `string.h` should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
  /* buffer large enough to hold 80 characters */
  char buf[80];
  int i;
  int n;

  printf("Please enter appointment: \n");
  n = read(STDIN_FILENO,buf,80); /* read a line */

  /* a keyword to search */
  #define KEYWORD_ADDM  "addM"
  #define KEYWORD_ADDM_SZ  (sizeof(KEYWORD_ADDM)-1)

  /* loop-find first space */
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    if ( buf[i] == ' ' )
      break;
  }
  if ( i == n )
  {
    /* space was not found in input */
  }
  else
  {
    /* space was found in input at index i */
    if ( ( i >= KEYWORD_ADDM_SZ ) && 
         ( strncmp( &buf[0], KEYWORD_ADDM, KEYWORD_ADDM_SZ ) == 0 ) )
    {
      /* match */
    }
    else
    {
      /* not a match */
    }
  }
```

Comment: if strncmp( &buf[0], KEYWORD_ADDM, KEYWORD_ADDM_SZ ) is match get the result is 0 it is cannot equal KEYWORD_ADDM_SZ

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the bulit-in library string.h It includes a number of functions that can help you to parse strings.

see:

string.h -
    strtok, strchr, strspn.